# asp.net redirect in firefox not working

Tags: asp.net, firefox, response.redirect

In my .net 3.5 web app i redirect users to another page using response.redirect.

This works in all ie browsers but not in firefox browsers.  i have no idea why?

```
Response.Redirect("~/"+ GlobalConsts.ARTICLE_ANALYSER_URL +"?"+ GlobalConsts.QUERYSTRING_KEY_ONE + 
            SessionHandler.RedirectToArticleID + GlobalConsts.QUERYSTRING_KEY_TWO + 
            SessionHandler.RedirectToArticleParentOrChild);
```

Comment: Is it possible to use Server.Transfer? I just tested an application in Firefox 6 using that and it worked correctly. The drawback is that the URL does not change, but depending on what your purpose is it may do what you need.

Comment: What happens when this line of code is executed?

Comment: Server.Transfer does not do a redirect; instead it displays another page as though it was the page currently requested. So even though the url shows /about.aspx you could show /default.aspx.

Answer (score 6):

Try installing this Firefox extension and recording the headers that are sent to the client:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829

The headers may give you some more insight into what is going wrong.

Comment: To the person who downvoted every answer on this question, it would really be nice to know your reasoning so we could improve the answers.

Comment: I dont know who downvoted but my guess is that it was related to client-side solutions whereas the OP wanted server-side.

Answer (score 3):

Always check with [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) first.

I like a suggestion made in the forum you linked, about it not being an error with redirections, but an issue with the browser cache. Try setting the expires header.

If the above doesn't do it, share more of your findings with fiddler.

Comment: unfortunately it's not an answer, sorry but it didn't help :(

Comment: @ILya what did fiddler show in your case? Pay attention to headers of the requests and status codes of the responses.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

Instead of using Response.Redirect just manually do the redirect:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Status = "302 Found";
Response.StatusCode = 302;
Response.AddHeader("Location", url);
Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

**Old Post**

It might be a caching issue, as according to this article http://www.mrclay.org/2011/07/03/firefox-5-shibboleth-issues/

And you might need to remove any caching headers you are sending along in the response. So set the cache headers to not cache and then response redirect:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache); 
Response.Redirect("~/"+ GlobalConsts.ARTICLE_ANALYSER_URL +"?"+ GlobalConsts.QUERYSTRING_KEY_ONE + 
            SessionHandler.RedirectToArticleID + GlobalConsts.QUERYSTRING_KEY_TWO + 
            SessionHandler.RedirectToArticleParentOrChild);
```

Comment: I updated the answer, I just wanted to make sure you saw the change.

Answer (score 0):

In firefox, check your **about:config** setting **network.http.redirection-limit** (which should be greater than 1).

A quick hint for general development troubleshooting with FireFox: Get the [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) extension.

Comment: I've checked that setting and its set to 20, still not sure what the problem could be....

Answer (score 0):

you can create a javascript function and call it when redirection needs to be done,

```
//javascript
function RedirectJS(url){
    window.location.href=url;
}
```

in the codebehind modify the onclick attribute of the button

```
//C#
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(!IsPostBack)
     {
          Button1.OnClientClick = "RedirectJS('"+HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath+"/"+GlobalConsts.ARTICLE_ANALYSER_URL +"?"+ GlobalConsts.QUERYSTRING_KEY_ONE + SessionHandler.RedirectToArticleID + GlobalConsts.QUERYSTRING_KEY_TWO + SessionHandler.RedirectToArticleParentOrChild+"');";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece:

```
Response.Redirect("~/"+ GlobalConsts.ARTICLE_ANALYSER_URL +"?"+ GlobalConsts.QUERYSTRING_KEY_ONE + 
            SessionHandler.RedirectToArticleID + GlobalConsts.QUERYSTRING_KEY_TWO + 
            SessionHandler.RedirectToArticleParentOrChild,false);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:
Response.RedirectPermanent(url, true);

Comment: Please stop posting this duplicate answer. It's not an answer to the questions you are posting it on.